# Extracting text between two defined variables

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import re
p = 1
while p < 10 and p>= 1:
    p = p+ 1
    primer = ("Artículo %so" % (p-1))
    ultimo = ("Artículo %so" % (p))
    with open("LISR.txt") as ley:
        texto_original = ley.read()
        fragmento = str(re.findall((r'primer(.*?)ultimo', texto_original, re.DOTALL))
```

I have a problem with the last line of code. I would like to extract the text between the two variables called `primer` and `ultimo`. The problem is that regex uses those words as strings, not variables. So I tried the following:

```
fragmento = str(re.findall((r'%s(.*?)%s' % primer, ultimo), texto_original, re.DOTALL))
```

which throws me the following error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) (emphasis mine)

> If `format` requires a single argument, `values` may be a single non-tuple object. [5] Otherwise, **`values` must be a tuple with exactly the number of items specified by the `format` string**, or a single mapping object (for example, a dictionary)

So you simply need to wrap your variables in parentheses, like so, to match your two `%s` formatting arguments

```
(r'%s(.*?)%s' % ( primer, ultimo ) )
                ^                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter is confused as to which arguments go to `findall` and which are to be used in formatting a string:

```
fragmento = str(re.findall((r'%s(.*?)%s' % (primer, ultimo)), texto_original, re.DOTALL))
```